# PowerShell $objSelection = $objOffice.Selection not working as a service

Tags: powershell, ms-word, office-interop, docx

I have a PowerShell script that reads a docx document, then does some find and replace operations and prints or saves it as a pdf. I call that script through a batch file.

When I call the script in a normal way, by double clicking, it works fine, but when I create a service (Using NSSM) that calls the batch file it fails.

The problem lies in the following line:

```
$objSelection = $objOffice.Selection
Write-Host "************ " $objSelection
```

When I call the script over the GUI I get the following:

```
************  System.__ComObject
```

But when I call it through a service I get the following

```
************
```

Meaning that when I attempt to use $objSelection.Find.Execute(...) the whole thing fails, as it attempts to do a null.Find.Execute(...)

```
Es ist nicht m”glich, eine Methode fr einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In C:\Users\Avejsic\Desktop\DruckenAlsService\PSConvertToPDF\OfficeFilePrint.ps1:193 Zeichen:13
+             $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWho ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Translation:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Does anyone have a idea why this happens and how to avoid the problem?

### EDIT:

I am using NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager to create a Windows service. How to use it:

1. It needs to be started over the console: "nssm64 install AAwsome-service"
2. Application->Path: select the "..." and select the batch which calls the PS1 script
3. ExitActions->Restart: No action (we wan the script to run only once)
4. I/O: Output(sdtout): select any *.txt document
5. Hit the "Install service" button

The batch file which executes the powershell:

```
powershell -Command "./PowershellScript.ps1"
```

The powershell script:

```
$DocumentName = "C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\Desktop\PS1_Extract\Document.docx" 
$SaveAsName = "C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\Desktop\PS1_Extract\DocumentOut.pdf"
$Printername = "Bullzip PDF Printer"
#$Printername = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer"

$objOffice = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$objOffice.DisplayAlerts = [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Word.WdAlertLevel]::wdAlertsNone
$objOffice.Visible = $false

$objDoc = $objOffice.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog($DocumentName)

$objSelection = $objOffice.Selection

Write-Host "--- objOffice ---" $objOffice
Write-Host "--- objSelection ---" $objSelection

        $FindText = "Test123"
        $ReplaceAll = 1
        $FindContinue = 1
        $MatchCase = $False
        $MatchWholeWord = $True
        $MatchWildcards = $False
        $MatchSoundsLike = $False
        $MatchAllWordForms = $False
        $Forward = $True
        $Wrap = $FindContinue
        $Format = $False
        $ReplaceText = "Success"


$objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceText,$ReplaceAll)

$objDoc.Close()
$objOffice.Quit()
```

Comment: We need to see your code.  Also, can you elaborate on what you mean when you say 'running through the Windows GUI works fine (what gui?), and then what NSSM is?

Comment: In your service, the object is `$Null` and in your manual execution, you're getting an object with a 
default `.ToString()` method.

Comment: Sorry for for my late reponse. Here is a code whith wich can the problem can be recreated. @FoxDeploy: When I start the batch file by double clicking it. I have added the full name of the program now. I feared that I could get banned due to the programs name